# Google GCM server for pushing Android notifications intermittently returning Unauthorized Error 401

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, unauthorized

We are pushing notifications to `Android` devices using `Google GCM api` from long time but from last 3-4 days we are getting `UNAUTHORIZED` error intermittently.

Sometimes all users are receiving the notifications and sometimes only 50-60% notifications are successful and for remaining we are getting `UNAUTHORIZED` error. So we can say that there is no issue in authentication key or authentication code.

There is no change in our code and code is written in `JAVA`.

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");

post.setHeader("Authorization", "key=" + headerKey);
post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
post.setHeader("Accept", "JSON");

ByteArrayEntity byteArray = new ByteArrayEntity(fieldsObject.toString().getBytes());
post.setEntity(byteArray);
```

Why would it sometimes return an Unauthorized Error?

Comment: Hi, you can use the form below to contact GCM support: https://support.google.com/code/contact/gcm_dev_support

Comment: @DiegoGiorgini: I have submit the form describing the issue for GCM support.